# Dropdown menu does not display elements when pressed

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a simple button in cshtml, that when pressed will display the elements of a list.
This is the code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - My Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
   ...
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
                  
        <div class="navbar-collapse col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse bg-dark sidebar collapse">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="dropdown" style="font-size: 20px">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                AAA
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4 pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
 
</div>

<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2022 - MySite - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

The issue, is that the button shows up, but when I press it the list does not show up.

[image]

What could be the issue here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A button will not magically do something. You need to attach an ActionListener or something similar to your button.

In this case, you're using bootstrap dropdown. You can find a working example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

The code example in question:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that where you use a `li class` and `ul class` the example (which you're probably emulating) uses a `div class`

Please update your tags with 'bootstrap' and remove C#

Comment: Hello Chrotenise.
Unfortunately this didn't work, replacing ul and li with div and placing the `aria-labelledby` field. I will update the changed code

Comment: @manuelmourato I see in your example that it's still not an exact match. Have you tried placing the exact code and seeing if a button will work?